# Map/Reduce multi level JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a list of rescues for ambulance drivers in different states that are displayed on a kanban board. My JSON object is divided by the status of the rescues, and then grouped by driver. The structure is like this:

--Status (unassigned/assigned/arrived/rescued)

----Driver group

-------Rescue list

The rescues have a datetime and lat/long associated with them, so I can use map/reduce to find the rescue that the drivers attended most recently, and show that location on a map.

One issue is that a driver group can exist in one swimlane and none of the other.

**I want to**: filter the list down to the arrived/rescued states only, (although logically this may not be necessary as it's not possible to have an arrival time without a driver associated, but this is out of scope) and for each driver group return their latest rescue by arrival time or rescue time. This will leave me with a distinct list of driver groups, with only the most recent rescue for that group

Here's the working code:

```
let groups = cases
                .filter(swimlane => parseInt(swimlane.rescueStatus) >= 3)
                .map(groups => groups.rescuerGroups)
                .map(rescuerGroups => rescuerGroups)
                .reduce((result, current) => {
                  
                  if(result.length === 0){
                    return current;
                  }
                  else{  
                    
                    current.forEach(currentRescueGroup => {
                      
                      let index = result.findIndex(parentRescueGroup => {
                        
                        return parseInt(parentRescueGroup.rescuer1) == parseInt(currentRescueGroup.rescuer1) &&
                            parseInt(parentRescueGroup.rescuer2) == parseInt(currentRescueGroup.rescuer2)
                        
                      })
                      
                      index > -1 ?
                        result[index].rescues = result[index].rescues.concat(currentRescueGroup.rescues)
                        :
                        result.push(currentRescueGroup);                          
                      
                    })
                    
                    return result;
                    
                    
                  }}, [])
                .map(rescueGroup => {
                                    
                  let maxRescue = rescueGroup.rescues.reduce((current, previous) => {
                  
                  let currentTime = new Date(current.ambulanceArrivalTime) > (new Date(current.rescueTime) || new Date(1901, 01, 01)) ? current.ambulanceArrivalTime : current.rescueTime;
                  let previousTime = new Date(previous.ambulanceArrivalTime) > (new Date(previous.rescueTime) || new Date(1901, 01, 01)) ? previous.ambulanceArrivalTime : previous.rescueTime;
           
              return previousTime > currentTime ? current : previous;
              
            })
              
             return {
                       rescuer1Abbreviation: rescueGroup.rescuer1Abbreviation,
                       rescuer2Abbreviation: rescueGroup.rescuer2Abbreviation,
                       latestLocation: maxRescue.latLngLiteral,
                       rescues: rescueGroup.rescues
                     }
           })
```

And here's a JSBin including the working code:

https://jsbin.com/hocasob/edit?js,console

Any help to make the reduce sections simpler would be much appreciated

Comment: One often given suggestion is to use a linter. One thing it will tell you, as an example, is that the `parseInt` requires a radix (it does not default to `10`). Another option would be to use the `Number` constructor instead. Also you could extract the accumulators outside as a variable and use argument destructuring.

Comment: Sorry I meant reducer instead of accumulator.

Answer (score 2):

*Turning a comment into a review (I provide an alternative implementation, but the basic ideas can be applied to the OP implementation).*

First, some general thoughts.
As I mention in the comments regarding the `parseInt` function, a linter can help spot any problems. A popular one is [ESLint](https://eslint.org). But perhaps more to the point, the data seems to already be a number, so there shouldn't be any need to parse it.

It can help to clean up the code quite a bit by extracting the filters, reducers, mappers, sorters, etc. outside as a variable and give them a descriptive name, for example:

```
// filter
const arrivedOrRescued = ({rescueStatus}) => rescueStatus >= 3

// sorter
const byArrivalOrRescueTime = (a, b) =>
  Date.parse(a.ambulanceArrivalTime || a.rescueTime)
    - Date.parse(b.ambulanceArrivalTime || b.rescueTime)

// reducer
const byRescuers = (acc, {rescuerGroups}) => {
  rescuerGroups.forEach(({
    rescues
    , rescuer1Abbreviation: r1
    , rescuer2Abbreviation: r2
  }) => {
    let group = `${r1}-${r2}`
    acc.has(group) ? acc.get(group).push(...rescues) : acc.set(group, rescues)
  })

  return acc
}
```

so getting a `Map` (just an example) by rescuers out of the swimlanes could then become

```
let rescuers = cases.filter(arrivedOrRescued).reduce(byRescuer, new Map())
```

and sorting their rescues could become

```
rescuers.forEach((rescues, abbrevs) => rescues.sort(byArrivalOrRescueTime))
```

after which the latest rescue is the last element of the array now that they have all been collected into a single array and sorted.

One thing I would like to promote here when there can be somewhat complex nested objects in the data, is to use [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app) comments to document the data shape.
For example:

```
/*
 * @typedef {Object} Swimlane
 * @property {Array.<RescuerGroup>} rescuerGroups
 * @property {Number} rescueStatus
 * @property {String} rescueStatusName
 *
 * @typedef {Object} RescuerGroup
 * @property {Array.<Rescue>} rescues
 * @property {?Number} rescuer1
 * @property {?Number} rescuer2
 * @property {?String} rescuer1Abbreviation
 * @property {?String} rescuer2Abbreviation
 *
 * @typedef {Object} Rescue
 * @property {?String} ambulanceArrivalTime
 * @property {?String} callDateTime
 * @property {?String} callerName
 * @property {String} callerNumber
 * @property {?Number} callOutcomeId
 * @property {Number} emergencyCaseId
 * @property {Number} emergencyCodeId
 * @property {Number} emergencyNumber
 * @property {Number} isLargeAnimal
 * @property {Number} latitude
 * @property {Number} longitude
 * @property {{lat: Number, lng: Number}} latLngLiteral
 * @property {String} location
 * @property {Array.<String>} patients
 * @property {Number} rescuer1
 * @property {Number} rescuer2
 * @property {?String} rescueTime
 * @property {Number} RescueStatus
 */
```

This makes it easier for others especially in data transformations.

*Just a note that I haven't tested any of this, so take the above code with a grain of salt. Also, many will probably tell me to use more braces and semicolons.*